# (Fósil hallado en Zapala, Neuquén) Fossil found in Zapala, Neuquén, Argentina

Tags: paleontology, fossils, identification-request

(Alguien podría decirme qué es?)

Could someone tell me what it is? Zapala is in Western Argentina, east of the Andes Mountains.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdqWd.jpg)

[image]

*English translation via Google Translate*

Comment: Welcome. Here is a guide on how to ask a good question about fossil identification. You can edit your post to add these informations. https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1760/18081